# send multiple mails in PHP

Tags: php, email

I have an issue with my code, I'am trying to send multiple mails at once to different users but it only sends the mail to the first mail in my mails list.

Can anyone help me find where the problem is located?

```
    function send_mails($filename, $from){
        $infos = combine_mails_to_passwords($filename);
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n" ;
        $headers .= "From: '$from'" . "\r\n";
        foreach($infos as $key => $info){
            $to = $info;
            $subject = "TEST Mail";
            $message = "<h2 style='font-size:18px;'>
            Voici vos identifiants pour passer l'évaluation</h2> 
            <div style='text-align:center;'>
            <table><tr><td><u>Login: </u></td> <td><b> ".$_SESSION['login']."</b><td></tr><br/> 
            <tr><td><u>Votre Mot de Passe: </u></td> <td><b> ".$key."</b></td></tr></table></div>";
            $from = "From: Company Name <TEST>";

            $ok = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            return $ok;
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['send-submit'])){

        if (!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']) && $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']!=''){
            $file_path = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
            $from = $_POST['from'];
            if($from!=""){
            if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'] != 'text/plain'){
                $error = "The file is not a text file!";
            }
            else if(count_mails($file_path)==0){
                $error = "The file is empty!";
            }
            else{

                if(send_mails($file_path, checkInput($from))){
                    $good = "Mails sent!";
                }
                else{
                    $error = "Connexion Problem!";
                }

            }
        }
            else{
                $error = "Please enter the email of the sender!";
            }
    }
    else{
        $error = "You did not import the emails file!";
    }
}
```

Note: The mails are uploaded from a text file.
Thank you!

Comment: _it only sends the mail to the first mail in my mails list..._ because you are leaving the loop after sending first email

Comment: You may not need to iterate, `to` accepts a string with the following format  `user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com`

Comment: @abestrad if you look at the code, the content of the message going to each address is slightly different (the $key variable is different). So I don't think that is a viable solution in this case.

Comment: @ADyson True that, missed that key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return $ok;` is the culprit...this means your function returns after the first time it loops, so the rest of it is never executed.

Instead you probably want to build up a list of the results of all the email attempts, so you can see which ones succeeded, and which failed. Then you can return that list at the very end of your function, after the loop ends.

Something like this (untested):

```
function send_mails($filename, $from){

    $infos = combine_mails_to_passwords($filename);
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n" ;
    $headers .= "From: '$from'" . "\r\n";

    $results = array(); //hold a list of results

    foreach($infos as $key => $info){
        $to = $info;
        $subject = "TEST Mail";
        $message = "<h2 style='font-size:18px;'>
        Voici vos identifiants pour passer l'évaluation</h2> 
        <div style='text-align:center;'>
        <table><tr><td><u>Login: </u></td> <td><b> ".$_SESSION['login']."</b><td></tr><br/> 
        <tr><td><u>Votre Mot de Passe: </u></td> <td><b> ".$key."</b></td></tr></table></div>";
        $from = "From: Company Name <TEST>";

        $results[$to] = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

and something like this to process the result and warn about failures:

```
$results = send_mails($file_path, checkInput($from));
foreach($results as $email => $result)
{
  if ($result == false) echo "Alert: Email to $email failed<br/>";
}
echo "All mail sent successfully apart from any which are alerted above";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it's working! Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

When you call `return $ok` within the `for` loop, you actually send only one mail. This might help, as it returns something after the loop has run for all elements:

```
function send_mails($filename, $from){
    $infos = combine_mails_to_passwords($filename);
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n" ;
    $headers .= "From: '$from'" . "\r\n";
    foreach($infos as $key => $info){
        $to = $info;
        $subject = "TEST Mail";
        $message = "<h2 style='font-size:18px;'>
        Voici vos identifiants pour passer l'évaluation</h2> 
        <div style='text-align:center;'>
        <table><tr><td><u>Login: </u></td> <td><b> ".$_SESSION['login']."</b><td></tr><br/> 
        <tr><td><u>Votre Mot de Passe: </u></td> <td><b> ".$key."</b></td></tr></table></div>";
        $from = "From: Company Name <TEST>";

        $ok = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
    return $ok;
}
```

...but it will only return the status for the last sent mail. You should define whether you want that method to return `true` when at least one mail was sent properly or only when **all** were sent and modify that variable based on that condition.

Answer (score 1):

you are put return inside of foreach loop, it will return the response in first iteration itself, so other emails will not be processed.

Comment: Can you add some further explanation to your answer? What should the OP do to solve this problem?